# daterangepicker trigger validation when I pick up a date

Tags: jquery, validation, daterangepicker

I'm using jquery validation with daterangepicker. I have an issue when I try to choose a date. When I choose it for the first time, it doesn't show "Hello" but the second time it shows "Hello" and what I really want to do is validate this field when I click on button next. How can I do to avoid that "checkDate" being executed when I pick up a date in order to validate it when I click on button next?

Here you can see my code:

```
$("#form_step1").validate({
    rules: {
        titulo: {
          required: true,
          maxlength: 300
        },
        reservationtime1:  {
          required: true,
          checkDate: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        titulo: "At least 300 characters",
        reservationtime1: "You must pick up a valid date"
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }    
});  
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkDate", function(value, element) { 
// My custom validation
alert("Hello");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B79z7/2/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Form validation won't work until you update values on input elements if you want to make it work give some default value to daterange input.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B79z7/6/)

```
  <input type="text" value="Enter the date " name="reservationtime1" id="reservationtime1" 
                        class="form-control" readonly="readonly"/>
```

**UPDATE** : Sorry I misunderstood the issue, if that's the case then move the validate() inside the #next.click method as #next is a anchor and there is no submit button, so as apply button click form validation methods got called.

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/B79z7/10/)

Comment: Actually I want to validate the date when i click on button next and not when I pick up a date.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `onfocusout:false,` to your validation options.

```
$("#form_step1").validate({
    onfocusout:false,
    rules: {
        titulo: {
          required: true,
          maxlength: 300
        },
        reservationtime1:  {
          required: true,
          checkDate: true
        }
    },
    //....
});
```

That seemed to limit the calls to `CheckDate` to only when the Next button was clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/B79z7/7/